# How to pass DEFAULT value in csv for pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, pgadmin, csv-import

Suppose I have values:

```
DEFAULT (serial), Wrocław (character varying), 1 (integer), 1 (integer)
```

but when importing I get errors about the first value. Since it's an ID I can't set it to integer or leave it empty.

Comment: how do you import csv content using pgAdmin? If you use the COPY-statement, only mention the fields that do have content. If you don't have the id, don't mention it.

Comment: thanks, I haven't noticed that "column" tab